# Color Grid in Excel by vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, background-color, is-empty

I need some help.

What I need is a code for colorid the Grid in Excel in this way:

- find the first cell with value ( 1 )
- find the last cell with value ( 2 )
- range (1:2)
- Color the grid black

My code by now:

```
'Color the columns A to K and ALL the rows below, no matter if they have a value or not.    
xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1), xlWorkSheet.Cells(xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count, 11)).Borders.ColorIndex = 0
```

I need to change the color of not-empty rows .

THX

Answer (score 0):

**Find the first cell :**

You should active the first cell (A1) and use **IsEmpty function**. 
Then you loop in the same column until you find a cell containing a value.

By the way, you need to keep the number of this row for the second point.

**Find the last cell :**

You have to exit your loop when it finds a new empty row. Then you'll get the range of cells using the number of first and last row.

You can check the [MSDN - "Empty Cells"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139976(v=office.10).aspx) to get more details.